# How do I generate a set of results from a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np

board=np.zeros((8,8))

for a in range(7):

    row=board[a,0:7]
```

I want to create a set of this results, named all_rows, but don't know how to do it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: To format your code: Select it and press CTRL+K

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list and append a row to that list each time through your loop:

```
all_rows = []
for a in range(7):

    row=board[a,0:7]
    all_rows.append(row)
```

Comment: @user7077252 glad to help!